# VB.NET event listener for click outside a form

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent

In VB.NET I can add an event listener for clicking inside a form, but I want the program to pick up clicks outside the form, when I am clicking elsewhere.  Is this possible?

Comment: You need to use something like this CodePlex project -- http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick, if there are no simpler solutions please add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a global mouse hook, the codeplex project [GlobalMouseKeyboardHook](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com) is one of the easier ways to accomplish it.