# Visual Studio 2008 Mouse and Key Down on out of form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, mouseevent, keydown

In Visual Studio 2008, how do I implement this code?

```
If MouseButtons() = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

    SendKeys.Send("{3}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("{1}")
End If
```

**When I press the left button of the mouse, I want it to send 3 & 1 to my Game.**

I'll be using this code for a game.

Comment: Please be a little more specific. What do you want this code to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I click left mouse buton, my program press 3 & 1.
And I click left mouse button not on form, but out of form...

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET event listener for click outside a form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210404/vb-net-event-listener-for-click-outside-a-form)

Comment: I still don't understand what "send 3" is supposed to mean. On its own it is not clear, and it could have been intended to mean any one of several things, so please be much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mouse click with this.

Add a timer "for my code  call it DeskClick"
Add a textbox called ShowMouseClick "so you can check"

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" _
 (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Private Const LBUTTON = &H1
Private Const RBUTTON = &H2

Private Sub DeskClick_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DeskClick.Tick
    If GetAsyncKeyState(LBUTTON) Then
        ShowMouseClick.Text = "Left Click"
    ElseIf GetAsyncKeyState(RBUTTON) Then
        ShowMouseClick.Text = "Right Click"
    Else
        ShowMouseClick.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

you also need to turn of PInvokeStackImbalance 
Go to Debug then select Exceptions Then MDA and deselect PInvokeStackImbalance

[image]
[image]

Maybe this is not the best way but it works perfect in my app Whit out any problem

---

To capture the event and do something

```
  Private Sub ShowMouseClick_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowMouseClick.TextChanged
    If ShowMouseClick.Text = "Left Click" Then

  TextBox1.Focus()
  SendKeys.Send("{3}")
  SendKeys.SendWait("{1}")

    End If
  End Sub
```